# нужен простой скрипт отслеживания текущей раскладки языка Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужен простой и менее костыльный скрипт отслеживания раскладки языка

например с таким условием:

```
if layout == '00001004':
     print("ru")
 elif layout == '00000000':
     print("en")
```

и если в момент когда запущен скрипт происходит смена языка, срабатывало все тоже условие, ну то есть скрипт **ожидает принудительного завершения**, а не закрывается после того как определил текущую раскладку.

Comment: В какой ОС и в какой графической подсистеме (или её отсутствии)?

Comment: @andreymal, Linux, вывод в терминал

Comment: Вывод не важен, важен ввод. Настоящий терминал или эмулятор терминала?

Comment: @andreymal, bash

Comment: bash это не терминал и не эмулятор терминала, в bash не существует никакой раскладки.

Comment: О, это очень интересная тема. Тут надо понимать, как раскладка языка работает в разных средах, начиная от чисто текстового интерфейса, и какое в этом всём принимает участие ядро ОС.